# Returning only first row when I use rs.next

Tags: groovy, soapui

When I use the same query using MySQL Workbench it seems to work properly and returns all rows(which is 2) . But When I do it using groovy it gives me only the 1st row. Not sure What I am doing wrong here.

Here is my code:

```
context.setProperty("Database", new Database());

import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.sql.*
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session


class Database{
    def queryDatabase(sqlQuery, table)
    {
        // ssh login
       String sshHost = 'test'
       String sshUser = 'test'
       String sshPass = 'test'
       int sshPort = 22


       // database login
       String targetHost = 'localhost'
        String targetUser = 'test'
        String targetPass = 'test'
        int targetPort = 3306
        int lport = 4322



        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(sshUser, sshHost, sshPort);
        session.setPassword(sshPass);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
        try {
        session.connect();
        int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, targetHost, targetPort);

        Connection con = null;
        String driver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mariadb://" + targetHost +":" + lport + "/";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, targetUser, targetPass);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        java.sql.ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String value = rs.getString(table);
            return (value)
            }
       }finally{
        session.disconnect()
        null
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not valid groovy.

Comment: I have pasted the full code.

Comment: Well, you return the value from inside the loop. So it doesn't continue. `return` immediately exists from the current method.You need to store the results in some data structure (a list, typically), and then return the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to different from your Java version

```
    while (rs.next()) {
        String value = rs.getString(table)
        return (value)
    }
```

This code returns the value immediately, instead of storing it in a temp variable and returning the whole list, so you could write something like this instead:

```
    def result = []

    while (rs.next()) {
        result << rs.getString(table)
    }

    return result
```

However, if you are going to rewrite this code to Groovy, why not use [groovy.sql.Sql](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) instead?

That way you can do things like:

```
List authors = sql.rows('SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Author')
```

(from the documentation [here](http://groovy-lang.org/databases.html))